# Test automation of Aptana (Eclipse) GUI

Tags: eclipse, testing, automation, automated-tests, aptana

I m looking for a tool able to automate tests for Aptana Studio's GUI. Google was not
too helpful in this case.

Thanks,

Shakov

Comment: Aptana is based on Eclipse. So, you are looking something which automates the Eclipse UI for your tests?  Or, are you looking to automate RoR or PHP tests?

Comment: I m looking for something that would automate the UI of Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking to automate the SWT GUI (SWT is the UI foundations of Eclipse). Google the term "SWT test automation" and see what comes up.

I know companies that use [QF Test](http://www.qfs.de/). It is an expensive option, but I know that it works well. Another option is to use [SWT Bot](http://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/) which is free.

Last week I also came across this very very cool project that can automate pretty much any UI called [Sikuli](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/). It is not geared so much towards testing, though.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely should take a look at Xored's [Q7 - Eclipse UI Testing](http://www.xored.com/q7).