# Automated UI testing for an Eclipse RCP application

Tags: testing, eclipse-rcp, user-acceptance-testing

What tools are available for record and play back type testing of an Eclipse RCP application?

I'm hoping for something that the end users will be able to pick up pretty easily and record their user acceptance tests with.

Comment: Can Selenium RC be used for such applications?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this:

http://code.google.com/p/robotframework-eclipselibrary/

Robot framework is one of the easier testing tools for end users to pick up as it nicely separates code from tests.

Answer (score 3):

[WindowTester](http://www.windowtester.com/) supports testing of SWT and Swing applications. It supports recording actions to Java tests. It was developed by Instantiations, which consistently delivered excellent products for Java development, integrated well within the Eclipse IDE. Google acquired Instantiations this year, and now offers WindowTester as *free software.*

[Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/products/editions.php), by FrogLogic, supports many UI toolkits, including SWT. I toyed with the Qt version a few years back, and liked it. Squish supports recording to scripts that you can then edit, in Python, JavaScript, Perl or Tcl. Scripts are not dependent on screen coordinates. On the downside, Squish is [exorbitantly priced](http://www.froglogic.com/products/licensing.php), and it's licensed per UI platform.

Some other options are described in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191906/test-automation-of-aptana-eclipse-gui).

Comment: windowtester pro moved to google :) the new link is http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wintester/html/index.html

Answer (score 3):

A comparision which includes most of the tools mentioned in the other answers (WindowTester, Squish, RCPTT, Jubula) can be found directly [on the Eclipse website](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Testing#UI_tests).

Answer (score 1):

This question is quiet old and the answers outdated. [RCPTT](http://eclipse.org/rcptt/) is a great if not the best solution to this problem. Free of charge and you are able to record user interactions

Comment: I thought that Jubula was Eclipse's offical testing project. It also has the features you mentioned. Have you tried using both of them? I wonder why they started a new project, there's not a single word about the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse foundation now has Jubula ptojext. See http://eclipse.org/jubula/ "Jubula"